# Panels in R with facet - high vertical bars it's the same but it should be different

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, panel, facet

Hallo I am trying to create a panel of images. However the result it's not the one I expect and I don't know what I am doing wrong.
My Code:

```
p <-ggbarplot(TT_phase_need, x = "Diet", y = "mean_hr_bpm_", add = c("mean_sd", "jitter"), ylab= "Heart Rate in supine position")
facet(p, facet.by = "Phase")
```

The result is this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoJ0K.png)

As you can see the error bars are in the right place but the vertical bars are not.
Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much!

Riccardo

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `ggpubr`, but I found two potential problems:

1. `facet.by = "Phase"` should be added in `ggbarplot()`. I guess that `facet(p, facet.by = "Phase")` in the second line is unable to correctly locate the `Phase` as the first line of code does not preserve such a variable (only a guess).
2. What you want might be `"mean_se"` instead of `"mean_sd"`?

Btw, I prefer the pure `ggplot2` as it is more widely used and well-documented.